# How to combine two base colors for Principled BSDF

Tags: texturing

I want to combine two base colors that I have exported from Substance Painter for a model I'm doing but there is only one channel to connect base color. Is there something I'm not doing right or is there no way to have multiple base colors

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Just to narrow the field - do you want your model to have two different colors? Or do you want to combine those colors into one? Both can be easily done, it's just not clear.

Comment: Use a color mix node and plug the result to the Principled BSDF. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. and please use a proper title for your questins.